# Can a 'delegate' property support multiple protocols?

Tags: objective-c, properties, delegates, protocols

I can find plenty of questions about making objects support multiple protocols but none confirming whether a @property can.  For example I have a class with a property of:

```
@property (strong) id dataSource;
```

The object passed in here supports the UITableViewDataSource protocol so I can assign it thus without problems, in ARC with no warnings:

```
self.tableView.dataSource = self.dataSource;
```

I'd like to also implement another protocol for say, searching, named CustomControllerSearchDelegate.  However if I start invoking random other methods ARC unsurprisingly starts complaining.  So we go down the protocol road defining it in in my object and making the property support it.  This then causes problems with assigning to the table data source.  So to the main question, can I do this:

```
@property (strong) id <UITableViewDataSource, CustomControllerSearchDelegate> dataSource;
```

and if not what is an appropriate alternative?

Or, what is the correct way to cast something to remove this compiler warning:

```
Assigning to 'id<UITableViewDataSource>' from incompatible type
'id<PickerViewControllerDataSource>'
```

Apologies if this is poorly explained. :/

-- Edit --

So my protocol is now defined as:

```
@protocol PickerViewControllerDataSource <UITableViewDataSource>
```

With the property defined as:

```
@property (strong) id <PickerViewControllerDataSource> dataSource;
```

Yet the compiler throws the following error:

```
No known instance method for selector 'objectAtIndexPath:'
```

-- Edit --

Declared above in custom protocol.  Declaration now reads:

```
@protocol PickerViewControllerDataSource <UITableViewDataSource>

- (id)objectAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;

@optional

- (void)searchDataWithString:(NSString*)string;
- (void)cancelSearch;

@end
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a protocol that incorporates other protocols, for example:

```
@protocol MyDataSourceProtocol <UITableViewDataSource, CustomControllerSearchDelegate>
@end
```

From the [Objective-C Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProtocols.html):

> One protocol can incorporate other protocols using the same syntax
>   that classes use to adopt a protocol:
>
> @protocol ProtocolName < protocol list >

Your `dataSource` property would then be defined as:

```
@property (strong) id <MyDataSourceProtocol> dataSource;
```

Alternatively your `CustomControllerSearchDelegate` protocol can incorporate the `UITableViewDataSource` protocol:

```
@protocol CustomControllerSearchDelegate <UITableViewDataSource>
  ... new methods here ...
@end
```

In this case, your `dataSource` property would then be defined as:

```
@property (strong) id <CustomControllerSearchDelegate> dataSource;
```

I personally prefer the latter approach.

Comment: Hmm I didn't know that, never really grokked the significance of the default <NSObject> in a protocol declaration.  Still if I do your first suggestion I get a compiler error. *updated question*  I'm AFK for a bit btw.

Comment: @Diziet There is no selector `objectAtIndexPath` in the `UITableViewDataSource` protocol, so that makes sense.

Comment: Thanks,  your've perfectly answered my question, protocol declarations themselves can inherit, thus the <nsobject> part has significance which I hadn't appreciated before.